# Download sqlite file from django

Tags: python, django

I have Django app that uses sqlite as database.
I wont to make view that will be able to download that sqlite file.

This is what I have got so far:

```
def backup(request):
    """Return Sqlite3 db file, if Sqlite3 db is used."""
    import settings

    db_engine = settings.DATABASES['default']['ENGINE']
    #db_engine = 'JUST_FOR_TESTING'

    if db_engine == 'django.db.backends.sqlite3':
        db_path = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']

        response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/x-sqlite3')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % db_path
        response.write(db_path)

        return HttpResponse(response)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("settings.DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] is %s,<br />\
                             only for 'django.db.backends.sqlite3' online backup is posible." % (db_engine))
```

What I am missing is how to add that file as attachment.

Also is there way somehow to download only specific tables ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are just trying to send the file path as attachment.

The relevant code is

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files import File
db_path = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']
dbfile = File(open(db_path, "rb"))
response = HttpResponse(dbfile, mimetype='application/x-sqlite3')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % db_path
response['Content-Length'] = dbfile.size

return response
```

Comment: This is working fine. I have just 2 more questions. 1: is there way to set default file name in web browser save dialog ? 2: Is there way to set web page to string like "Backup done", because currently content of webpage is what is left from last page.

Comment: 1. `filename` in `Content-Disposition` header would provide default name. 2. I think you need to use ajax for this. Download using ajax call, and update page when done. However, I haven't done that.

Comment: 1. you are right, but problem was in '\' and '//' separators, so I replaced db_path with db_path.split(os.sep)[-1] 2. is there some way to redirect to another view after, this one ? Because that I could use that, as hack :-)

Comment: 2. I don't think so. Each HTTP request has 1 response. In this case downloading file is your response. So you can't sent another response!

Comment: The `mimetype` should now be `content_type` as of 2018.